# Blazor. How can I get current url in the Startup class (method ConfigureServices)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I am using AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB. The database name depends on hostname. I am trying to get hostname using NavigationManager but it seems in the Startup.ConfigureServices it is not initialized.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       // Server Side Blazor doesn't register HttpClient by default
        if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
        {
            // Setup HttpClient for server side in a client side compatible fashion
            services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
            {
                NavigationManager uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
                return new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
                };
            });
        }

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddTransient<ILiteDbContext>(s =>
                {
                    NavigationManager uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
                    Uri currentUrl= uriHelper.ToAbsoluteUri(uriHelper.BaseUri);
                    return new LiteDbContext(new LiteDatabase(this.GetUserDatabasePath(currentUrl)));
                }
            );

        //services.AddTransient<ILiteDbContext, LiteDbContext>();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB.IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })
        .AddUserStore<LiteDbUserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
        .AddRoleStore<LiteDbRoleStore<AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB.IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I have the exception: 
InvalidOperationException: 'RemoteNavigationManager' has not been initialized.

[image]

As I understood NavigationManager is not initialized when Identity is being initialized. Is there a way to get the current URL without NavigationManager?

Comment: Don't think you can do that. The app doesn't knows anything about the domain it's running until someone calls it, so NavigationManager can't give you any info until it's called inside a request. What if you check the initialization at request level? If BaseAddress isn't set when you receive a request then use NavigationManager to set it.

Comment: Put it in configuration?

Comment: If it's server-side, will HttpContext.Current.Request give it to you?

Comment: @Gusman yep, you right. It is needed to do it somehow at the first request. Maybe reinitialize dbrequests, I am not sure now about the best approach.

Comment: @Gusman isn't Transient and Scoped per request? Meaning the information is known somewhere when the factory is called. Problem here is that NavigationManager is not fully initialized when the factory is called.

Comment: @hultqvist read what yourself have said: "per request". At the intialization stage there is no request, so there is no domain information. If the problem was just the scope you could use the scope factory to create one and retrieve the service, but there would be still no domain info as there is no incomming request containing the URL information.

Comment: @gusman I meant that since the lifetime is per request that would mean that the factory lambda must be called once per request. The lambda is defined before the are any request, but it will be called once per request, at that time the request would exist.

Answer (score 2):

Is this Blazor server-side or blazor-client-side?
If client-side you can use the `IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment` interface to get the `BaseAddress` of the app.
You can do something like this in your CSB `Program.cs`

```cs
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
    var baseAddress = hostEnvironment.BaseAddress;
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Blazor server-sid

Comment: `IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment` is only available in the client

Answer (score 0):

I have Blazor WASM hosted and my server needed the host uri in order to provide it to 3rd party as a callback parameter.

In case you use `.razor` file on the server you can use:

```
NavigationManager.BaseUri
```

But in my case, in API call I have used Request information to get needed uri:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("EndpointName")]
public ActionResult EndpointName()
{
    var serverUri = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}";
}
```